# Difference between "defining" and "declaring"

Tags: c, initialization, terminology, declaration, definition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

I am trying to thoroughly understand "defining" and "declaring" in C.

I believe `x` here is defined, since external variables are automatically initialized to 0, and something that's declared and initialized is defined. Is that accurate?

```
int x;
main() {}
```

According to one `x` in this case is a definition, but why? It is not being initialized...

```
int print_hello()
{
  int x;
}
```

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration/1410632#1410632) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring is telling the compiler that there's a variable out there that looks like this.

Defining is telling the compiler that this is a variable.

One refers to the existence of a thing, the other is the thing.

In your example, the scope is what makes the difference.  Declarations are made in a file scope, but in a block scope it is not possible to declare anything; therefore, the second example is a definition; because, there is nothing left to do with the `int x;`.

That makes the first example (in the file scope) a declaration that some `int x;` exists.  To covert it from a declaration, you need to specify that a value is assigned to it, forcing the memory allocation.  Like so: `int x = 0;`

C and C++ are very scope sensitive when it is analyzing constructs.

Comment: thanks but I understood that much :) Edit: so , its defined because thats the only alternative ?? I think I'll just have to mugup this .

Comment: Sorry, I hit submit too soon so I had to edit it to add the part that dealt with your actual question.

Comment: but his first example is also a definition, no?

Comment: Actually the first example is not a definition, it is only a declaration.  To convert it to a definition, you need to assign a value to it.  The rules differ slightly between C and C++.  That's why it is far better to enforce the use of the `extern` keyword.

Comment: the first is definitely a definition.. i think

Comment: Tentative definitions are different from regular definitions.  Edwin is pretty much accurate, except that a tentative definition is not a simple forward declaration, it is a definition, but there can be more than one of them that refer to the same object.  Be careful!

Answer (score 1):

"Define" does not mean "initialized." It means something is created, rather than just referenced.

A definition allocates but does not necessarily initialize memory. This can lead to fun debugging.

Comment: so even if a variable hasn't been initialized it can be defined ? but i read that definition = declaration + initialization, here - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1501482&page=1

Comment: From c-faq: "definition - n. 1. A declaration of a variable or function which allocates and optionally initializes (in the case of a variable) or provides the function body (in the case of a function)." -- http://c-faq.com/sx1/index.html#definition

Comment: should have read that... ok so the answer is yes. even if a variable hasn't been initialized it can be defined. The point is that for definition memory has to be allocated ?

Comment: For variables, yes, a definition allocates memory. There are other, um, definitions for other constructs. Common among all is that there can be a single definition, but multiple declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Declaration introduces a name in a TU. Definition instantiates/allocates storage for that name.

```
int x; //definition,also a declaration. Every definition is a declaration.
int main(){}
```